# JavaScript event handling (registering multiple handlers) for non-DOM objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

In .NET you can add multiple handlers to an event which an object declares as an event.

What is the recommended way for handling this in JavaScript for non-DOM objects?

i.e. I have an object:

```
var ProblemDomainObj = {} ;
ProblemDomainObj.Changed = function() {} ;
ProblemDomainObj.Data = { somedata : "initialized" } ;
ProblemDomainObj.Operate = function (newdata) {
    if (newdata != somedata && ProblemDomainObj.IsValid(newdata)) {
        somedata = newdata;
        ProblemDomainObj.Changed();
    }
} ;
```

Now other objects may want to register to know that the data has changed and each want to do something like this:

```
ProblemDomainObj.Changed += function() {
     /* Do stuff to reflect the object model changes */
} ;
```

Where each gets to register their handler without overwriting the other.

Then some object will call `ProblemDomainObj.Operate(foo);` and all those who have subscribed will get notified.

I have found the documentation in jQuery for http://api.jquery.com/on/ but it seems to relate to DOM events like onclick.  None of this would necessarily be related to the DOM.

Comment: Your writing C# in JavaScript. You might want to step back and learn javascript thoroughly

Comment: @Raynos Is there a native idiom in JavaScript that negates the need for subscribing to events for objects so that you can decouple components from knowing about other components who want to be informed about events they raise?

Comment: No, but writing one is 10 lines, as shown

Comment: @Raynos I appreciated your pubsub answer, but I'm missing your point.  Javascript hasn't changed a lot in 16 years, but it's used a lot differently (maturely) in the last 6 years as frameworks have established conventions.  I'm trying to bring my practices into line with latest convention as we are doing far more complex coding in JavaScript than we used to do.  I think that code should be good JavaScript as well as good software, in the same way that the SQL or C# or HTML or CSS we write uses the established native idioms and best practices of each language or environment.

Comment: again there is no native way to do events. The DOM has an event model you can use but it's expensive. Use your own little event emitter, that is the standard way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery works great on regular objects as well: http://jsfiddle.net/gMNkg/.

```
var ProblemDomainObj = {};

ProblemDomainObj.Data = { somedata : "initialized" };

ProblemDomainObj.Operate = function () {
    $(ProblemDomainObj).trigger("foo"); // run bound functions
};


// bind 2 functions

$(ProblemDomainObj).on("foo", function() {
    alert(123);
});

$(ProblemDomainObj).on("foo", function() {
    alert(456);
});


ProblemDomainObj.Operate();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function PubSub() {
    return {
        events: {},
        sub: function (event, handler) {
            if (!this.events[event]) {
                this.events[event] = [];    
            }
            this.events[event].push(handler);
        },
        pub: function (event, data) {
            this.events[event] && this.events[event].forEach(publishData);

            function publishData(handler) {
                handler(data);   
            };
        }
    };   
}

var pubsub = PubSub();
pubsub.sub("changed", f);
pubsub.sub("changed", g);
pubsub.pub("changed", o);
```

You basically want a tiny event system where you can say "I want to subscribe to this event" and "I want to publish this event".

I recommend you write your own little event system.

You will have to integrate this object into your system. It will probably work best as a mixin.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using jQuery, you could do add custom events on any objects.

```
var obj = {a:1,b:2};
$(obj).on('changed', function() { alert('Changed once'); });
$(obj).on('changed', function() { alert('Changed twice'); });

$(obj).trigger('changed');
```

[Run the code](http://jsfiddle.net/gExYS/)

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way using closure

```
ProblemDomainObj.Changed = (function(previousChangeEvent) {
     return function () {
       if (previousChangeEvent) {
          previousChangeEvent();
       }
       /* Do stuff to reflect the object model changes */
     }
})(ProblemDomainObj.Changed) ;
```